# "Two valid but unequal nodes with the same `data-reactid`" - How to fix

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that I am rendering where I use some jquery to create new input fields based on the div that is already rendered. I am still learning react, and I am getting the error of the two valid but unequal nodes with same data-reactid. I know its because I am just cloning the same div back into the dom, but any tips on the basic way to solve this? Been looking into keys but don't know how to put them in place. Thanks in advance.

component:

```
var AddNew = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {name: '', quantity: '', price: ''}
  },
  nameChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({name: e.target.value});
  },
  quantityChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({quantity: e.target.value});
  },
  priceChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({price: e.target.value});
  },
  createNewInput: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".add-new:last").clone().insertAfter("div.add-new:last");
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
      <div className="new-section">
        <div className="add-new">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <label>Name</label>
              <input className="add-name" type="text" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.nameChange} />
            </li>
            <li>
              <label>Quantity Available</label>
              <input id="quantity" type="number" value={this.state.quantity} onChange={this.quantityChange} />
            </li>
            <li>
              <label>Price</label>
              <input id="price" type="number" value={this.state.price} onChange={this.priceChange} />
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button className="add-another" onClick={this.createNewInput}>+ Add another Input</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend a more "reactive" approach.

Instead of using jquery:

- initialise the state with an array (to store the state of the multiple sets of input items)
- render the elements from the array
- when the `Add another set of inputs` button is clicked, a new empty object `{name: '', quantity: '', price: ''}` is added into the array and immediately rendered, as the render method is called each time the state changes.

The html inputs and other tags that you render for each object in the array should be wrapped in one html element, let's say a div. If you put a `key` attribute with a unique value to this div you will get rid of the `data reactid` error.

But better to show the code I had in mind (you can also see it in action here: https://jsbin.com/tinoda/edit?js,console,output):

```
var AddNew = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {elements:[]}
  },
  nameChange: function(index, e) {
    var elements = this.state.elements;
    elements[index].name = e.target.value;

    this.setState({elements: elements});   
    console.log(this.state.elements);
  },
  quantityChange: function(index, e) {
    var elements = this.state.elements;
    elements[index].quantity = e.target.value;

    this.setState({elements: elements});   
    console.log(this.state.elements);
  },
  priceChange: function(index, e) {
    var elements = this.state.elements;
    elements[index].price = e.target.value;

    this.setState({elements: elements});   
    console.log(this.state.elements);
  },
  createNewSet: function(e) {
    var elements = this.state.elements;
    elements.push({name: '', quantity: '', price: ''});

    this.setState({elements: elements});
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="new-section">
        {this.state.elements.map((element, index) =>
          <div key={index}>
            <div>
              <label>Name</label>
              <input className="add-name" type="text" value={element.name} onChange={this.nameChange.bind(this, index)} />
            </div>
            <div>
              <label>Quantity Available</label>
              <input className="add-name" type="text" value={element.quantity} onChange={this.quantityChange.bind(this, index)} />
            </div>
            <div>
              <label>Price</label>
              <input className="add-name" type="text" value={element.price} onChange={this.priceChange.bind(this, index)} />
            </div>
          </div>
        )}

      <button className="add-another" onClick={this.createNewSet}>+ Add another set of inputs</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Much appreciated. Pretty new with React and I didn't want to incorporate jquery. But this solves it.

Comment: Thanks again Alexandru. Just wondering, how would you go about having the inputs render first with the button below to add more. Right now you have to click the button for any inputs to show up. I am wanting the input to show up on load, then click the button to add any additional items.

Comment: Welcome, glad it helps! Minor change for getting an input set on load. In `getInitialState` return `{elements:[{name: '', quantity: '', price: ''}]}` instead of `{elements:[]}`. This way you initialise the state of the component with an array which contains a set of empty values for a set of inputs. The `getInitialState` function is called only once, when the component is mounted. Fully working example [here](http://codepen.io/alexchiri/pen/BKjJYj).

Comment: Seriously Alexandru, you are the man. I created a delete button function and just used .pop instead of push and woolah. Many thanks!!! Been having trouble thinking in React vs regular javascript and jquery.

Comment: You're welcome! Give it time, it takes a little while and with all these modules it can be quite overwhelming. I find lots of new stuff every day in react. If you find my previous comment useful, please consider giving it an upvote, helps for the reputation! :-) Answering stuff on StackOverflow helps a lot in learning, after you get going a bit.